# Change cell height in a table when sending HTML email to Gmail

Tags: html, css, gmail, html-email

I'm trying to send out an HTML email from Outlook 2013 to Gmail but I noticed that I get a big gap between the rows. I can not change the height of the rows no matter what I do.  I'm looking for some advice to fix this. Here is my code:

```
  <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
            border-spacing: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="font-family: Arial; color: #646464; font-size: 8pt">
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 9pt; padding-bottom: 7px;">Test User</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 0; border-top: solid 1px #646464;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try setting `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` attributes of table?

Comment: Can you try making the problem show up on JSfiddle.net? I just copied your code, but don't see any big gaps.

Comment: @Rvervuurt It's impossible to reproduce email rendering problems in anything but the specific email client you're having problems with.

Comment: @learningloop I tried that already but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try inlining your `border-collapse` and `border-spacing` css to your table. GMail strips the style tag before parsing.

For that second `<td>` you should set `height="1"`. The height attribute for `<td>`s is how you set the height of rows. That nbsp fix is good for Outlook '13, but watch out that you don't use it too often. SpamAssassin sees any font-size less than 5px as possible spammy content.